# stat function : no such file or directory error

Tags: c++, c, freebsd, stat

When my program tries to `stat()` a file containing specific UTF-8 characters, the `stat()` function returns an error. For example, I can open the file `/tmp/surgateDlpMgQure/Özkul Gazete` with vi, but passing this same file to `stat()` generates an error. System locale settings are:

> LANG=en_US.UTF-8
>
> LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
>
> LC_COLLATE=C
>
> LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
>
> LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
>
> LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
>
> LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
>
> LC_ALL=

Should I do something in order for `stat()` to understand the UTF-8 characters?

Here is the code:

```
int main ()
{
    struct stat s;
    if (stat("/tmp/surgateDlpMgQure/Özkul Gazete", &s) == -1)
            perror("stat");


    switch (s.st_mode & S_IFMT) {
            case S_IFBLK:  printf("block device\n");            break;
            case S_IFCHR:  printf("character device\n");        break;
            case S_IFDIR:  printf("directory\n");               break;
            case S_IFIFO:  printf("FIFO/pipe\n");               break;
            case S_IFLNK:  printf("symlink\n");                 break;
            case S_IFREG:  printf("regular file\n");            break;
            case S_IFSOCK: printf("socket\n");                  break;
            default:       printf("unknown?\n");                break;
    }

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: can you post the code ...so we can know how you use stat() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is probably that the encoding of the file name isn't the
same as the encoding you're using internally in your program.  The key
questions here are who created the file (and gave it this name), and
where the string in your code comes from.  Most of Unix is agnostic with
regards to the encoding, as long as a few special characters, like
`'/'`, have the expected encoding.  Thus, **independently of your
current locale**, a file name can be in Latin-1, Latin-5 (just guessing,
but the name looks Turkish) or UTF-8.  Practically nothing in Unix cares,
but *you* have to ensure that in your program, you use the same encoding
as was used to create the file, or the names won't match.  (In practice,
I've found the simplest policy to be to limit the characters in a
filename to a very small set: the ASCII alphanumeric characters, digits,
`'_'` and possibly `'-'`.)

If you're not sure about the actual encoding of the filename on disk,
you can use `ls | od -t x1 -tc` to find out the actual value of the
bytes in it.  If your `Ö` is 0xD6, then the encoding is either Latin-1
or Latin-5 (and it probably won't make much difference which), and
you'll have to ensure that the filename you pass `stat` (or `open`, or
any other functions which take a filename) is encoded in one of these
encodings.  If instead you have the two byte sequence 0xC3, 0x96, then
the filename is UTF-8.

If you do want to support characters outside of the ASCII subset, then
I'd strongly recommend that you ensure that *all* filenames are encoded
in UTF-8.  Supposing that you can—the encoding will be decided by
the program creating the file, and if it's not your program (or if
you're receiving the file from another system), you may not be able to
do anything about it.  In the worst case scenario, you may even have to
use `opendir` and `readdir` with some sort of matching algorithm to find
the actual filename (in whatever the encoding), and use it.

Answer (score 0):

i think there is problem due to space in name of that filename...

can you try with changing that filename without space

```
Özkul Gazete  -> Özkul_Gazete
```

On linux usually i dont use space in filename or directory name

Answer (score -1):

easy way to hack around it :

use the escaped representation of that unicode character:

`"/tmp/surgateDlpMgQure/\x00\xF6zkul Gazete"`

I did not test, but it shall work. Though it's not the way to go with unicode strings in C.

weirdly enough, your code works on my system, but not mine :)

Comment: It can't possibly work with the string you give, since `\00` is a null character, which will be treated as the end of the string by `stat`.